# How can i send stickers from whatsapp-web.js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp

web.js library, and i can't found a way to send stickers.
I see for Util(), but gives me an error (Util is not a constructor). Whats the correct form of use Util(), or how can i send stickers ?

Answer (score 3):

### Make sure of your version

First of all, make sure that you are using the version (**`v1.12.4` or newer**). Because they fixed an issue with stickers on `v1.12.4`.

---

### Sending stickers

You can send stickers with the library! Stickers are sent just like any other media type. You just need to make sure to specify the option `sendMediaAsSticker: true` when sending the message:

```
const sticker = MessageMedia.fromFilePath('/path/to/image.png');
chat.sendMessage(sticker, { sendMediaAsSticker: true });
```

The library takes care of converting the media internally to an acceptable format.

Animated stickers are also supported, but it's worth noting that conversion to webp is done through ffmpeg. You'll need to have it installed if you want to send animated stickers that are not already in webp format. By default the ffmpeg path is set to `ffmpeg`, but if you have it installed in a different path, you can set it manually when creating the client like so:

```
const client = new Client({
    ffmpegPath: '/path/to/ffmpeg.exe'
});
```

---

The sources:

1. [here](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/releases/tag/v1.12.0)
2. [here](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/releases/tag/v1.12.4)